# how to redirect back to previous page in django?

Tags: django, page-refresh, django-1.2

I'm new to django

I'm working on a voting application, and I need to stay on the same page after casting a vote

Meaning that I want to refresh the page without leaving it and display a success message

Here is my view.py (where I set and check cookies to avoid double votes):

```
@render_to('user/books_list.html')  
def vote(request, object_id):
voted=request.session.get('has_voted',[])
books = Book.objects.get(id=object_id);

if object_id in voted:         
    return {
                'object': books,
                'error_message': "You have already voted.",
            }
else:
    books.votes += 1
    books.save()
    request.session['has_voted']=voted+[object_id]
    return locals()
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('user.views',

    url(r'^books/$', 'books_list', name="books_list"),
    url(r'^books/(?P<object_id>\d+)$', 'book_detail', name="book"),
    url(r'^books/vote/(?P<object_id>\d+)$', 'vote', name="vote"),  
)
```

Here is my template :

```
{% if list_participant %}

{% for book in list_books %}

{{ book.name }} 

    <a href={% url vote book.id %}  >vote</a>

    {{ book.votes }} 

  {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

The way I'm doing it now it redirect me to books/vote/x
I'd like it to redirect to the previous page ,which is books/

Any idea please
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

so what I did is to add the vote processing inside the same view that display the books and use an if Post condition to detect when the vote button is clicked

```
@render_to('user/list_books.html')  
def list_books (request):    
    books_list = Book.objects.all()

  if request.POST:
    voted=request.session.get('has_voted',[])
    p_id=request.POST['id']
    book = Book.objects.get(id=p_id);
    if p_id in voted:         
        return {
                'notvoted': book,
                'error_message': "You have already voted for this book today!",
                'books_list': books_list
                }
    else:
        book.votes += 1
        book.save()

        vote = Vote() 
        vote.book_id = p_id
        vote.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')       
        vote.save()

        request.session['has_voted'] = voted+[p_id]
        request.session.set_expiry(86400)#one day in seconds
        return {
                 'books_list': books_list,
                 'voted' : 1 ,
                 'book' : book
                }
else :
    return {'books_list': books_list}
```